# How to remove the emphasis for the internal hyperlink in sphinx documentation

Tags: css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

Cross-referencing in sphinx is done using `ref` , like:

```
.. _my-reference-label:

Section to cross-reference
--------------------------

This is the text of the section.

It refers to the section itself, see :ref:`my-reference-label`.
```

When compiled to HTML, above would introduce a hyperlink after "see", but would also embed it within the `<em>` tag, making internal references look different from external hyperlinks.

Is there any way to instruct sphinx not to emphasize internal references, that is, not to embed them within the `<em>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a line to your CSS file:

```
a.internal {font-style: normal}
```

In order for Sphinx to use a custom CSS file you need to edit `conf.py`:

```
html_style = 'my_style.css'
```

Then put the file in the `_static` directory, or whichever directory you have declared with `html_static_path`.

Then `my_style.css` might look like:

```
@import url("default.css");  /* This should be the file used by your theme */

/* Internal links */
a.internal {font-style: normal}
```

This will not get rid of the surrounding `<em>` tag but should work to style your docs correctly.

Comment: The last code line must read `a.internal em {...`.  The "em" is missing.  As it is now, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own [theme](http://sphinx-doc.org/theming.html) and [template](http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html) to do this.